# How to deploy Kitura generated Server Side Swift Build on Tomcat

Tags: swift, kitura

I wanted to check if somebody has explored the option of deploying Kitura compiled project on TomCat? Basically, is it possible to deploy the build outside IBM cloud environment?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you can run Kitura **instead of** Tomcat. Kitura is an *embedded web server*, you do not need other web server to run a Kitura application. So you can build a Kitura application on macOS/Linux and run the compiled executable on macOS/Linux. It will listen to the port you specify, receive HTTP requests and route them to the request handling code of your application.

Comment: Right. But how can I deploy this application in a central server which is accessible via network not with local host port.

Comment: You can just run a Kitura application on a macOS/Linux machine and it will listen to a port of the machine. Then you can access this machine thru its IP address or its URL, with the port Kitura runs on. That's all.

Comment: Suppose the URL of your macOS/Linux machine is `www.example.com`. Then you can run Kitura in that machine and let it listen, for example, on port 8090. Then you can access your Kitura app by URL `http://www.example.com:8090`.

Comment: To clarify more - when you perform `swift build`, an executable file with Kitura application is produced in `.build/debug/<Your Application Name>`. Then you can just run this executable in a command line on your machine, no need to perform any special deployment.

Comment: As @VadimEisenberg says, also you can 

swift build -c release 

for when you want to run this under real workloads and run your app with 

.build/release/<Your Application Name>